# Приложение не совместимо ни с одним из ваших устройств. После публикации

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, google-play-console

Всем привет, буквально 6-8 часов назад приложение опубликовалось на play market-e, требования android 4.4 и выше. Почему то на всех устройствах пишет "Приложение несовместимо с вашим устройством."

Кто нибудь сталкивался с подобным, я не знаю в чем может быть дело, к примеру нужен ли play service если даже нет рекламы, может что-то с манифестом.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.amirapps.imdod.ru">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.Camera"/>
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera2"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"></activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Откройте ваш манифест и переключитесь в режим [Merged Manifest](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge#inspect_the_merged_manifest_and_find_conflicts) - так вы увидите всё, что туда добавили библиотеки и сборщик. Если не сможете определить что там мешает - выкладывайте сюда

Comment: @woesss я не понял что мешает, по этому выложил весь манифест

Comment: @woesss android:required = false только что поставил, до этого не было

Comment: Сделайте в вопросе так же как в публикации. И подождём товарищей, которые уже работали с камерой))) И всё же проверьте ещё в merged режиме

Comment: @woesss хотел в комментах привести манифест не получилось, пришлось добавить манифест в вопрос.

Comment: Всё правильно - комменты для коротких уточнений, а для кода всей полезной информации - вопрос и ответ

Comment: @woesss android:required не было в первичном варианте, сейчас обновил и на консоле уже есть поддерживаемые устройства

Answer (score 1):

Дело в камере, изначально во время публикации оно было обязательным. 
Надо добавить android:required = "false".

```
  <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.Camera"
    android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera2"
    android:required="false" />
```